# Android textview with scrollbars inside a layout with scrollbar

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

That's xml file with layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sc"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/openText"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, I have a TextView with id "openText", and on click on button it appears (scrollable) with text, height i set programmatically,

```
TextView openText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openText);
openText.setMaxHeight(textHeight);
```

Everything is fine, but when an image has a big height so a main scrollview appears, it only scrolls, and a textview stops scrolling :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add following line, now it works!

```
openText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```